# ggplot2: How can I get rid of a geom_point redundant colour code with an empty legend when there are NA values in the data.frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As you can see in the figure, there is an annoying pink dot in the legend with an empty legend in there (in the "Tissue" legend section above "2"). I know it is due to the ifelse statement in the geom_point colour option, but is there a way I can get rid of the pink dot and keep the rest the same?
I cannot drop the NA because I need to plot them in the figure and show that particular value is missing.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks guys!

```
df<- data.frame("SN" = 1:6, "Age" = c(21,15,10,23,56,78),"Score"=as.factor(c(20,49,60,54,23,43)), "bmi"=c(18,19,NA,NA,22,23), "Tissue"= c("heart","lung","skin", "brain", "heart","lung"))

p<- ggplot(df, aes(x = bmi, y=Score)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=Age,colour=(ifelse(is.na(df$bmi),"",Tissue)))) +
  geom_text(label=(ifelse(is.na(df$bmi),"",df$Tissue)), hjust = 0, nudge_x = 0.025, check_overlap = FALSE, colour="black") 

p + labs(size="Age", colour="Tissue")
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to keep the NAs?

Comment: It seems like you are just trying to drop the values where bmi is NA. Just do that on the data parameter and things get much easier: `p<- ggplot(subset(df, !is.na(bmi)), aes(x = bmi, y=Score)) + geom_point(aes(size=Age, colour=Tissue)) + geom_text(aes(label=Tissue), hjust = 0, nudge_x = 0.025, check_overlap = FALSE, colour="black") `

Comment: I cannot drop the NA because in the real dataset I want to show in the plot that value is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a reason to keep the NA values; if you don't want to remove them from your data, you don't have to, but you can filter them out when you make the plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
    filter(!is.na(bmi)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = bmi, y = Score)) +
        geom_point(aes(color = Tissue, size = Age)) + 
        geom_text(aes(label = Tissue), hjust = 0, nudge_x = 0.025, check_overlap = FALSE, colour="black") +
        labs(size="Age", colour="Tissue")
```

There's also no reason to assign your axis labels in a separate call, I would just do them all together like the code above. Also keep in mind that you shouldn't need to call the name of the dataframe when you're referencing variables in `ggplot` calls, e.g., you need `Tissue` rather than `df$Tissue`; if you find yourself needing the latter, then you probably want to reshape your data more appropriately before calling `ggplot`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer heds1, but what if I need to keep "Score" = c(60,54) in the y-axis even though the corresponding bmi value is missing?

Comment: Where do you want your one-dimensional `score` datapoint to be plotted on a two-dimensional plot..?

Comment: I don’t want them to be plotted. I hope to show that the Score on the y-axis is there but the corresponding BMI value is missing. I meant to treat the “Score” as a factor rather than numeric. I know it may sound confusing why treating the “Score” as a factor, but in my real dataset the “Score” corresponds to a particular study, e.g., Study 1, Study 2, etc. Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly do you want the plot to look like? Are you sure a scatterplot is the best way to represent this data?

Comment: Hi heds1, I want the plot to look just like the figure above, but without the pink dot in the "Tissue" legend. I think the scatterplot is a good choice to represent the data. Thanks.

Comment: Are you just trying to say you want to increase the y-axis limits??

Comment: No. I want the y-axis to display all these study points: “Score"=as.factor(c(20,49,60,54,23,43))